# :contains без учета регистра

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте.
Делаю фильтрацию для элементов.
Но проблема в том, что учитывает регистр селектор `:contains.`
Есть альтернатива?

Спасибо.

```
$('#results .result')
    .show()
    .children('.name')
    .data('name')
    .not(':contains(' + filter + ')')
    .parent('.result')
    .hide();
```

Comment: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/278

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Иногда интересно, как люди гуглят.

http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/v4auH/

Comment: Спасибо, но точно также зделал, и далее регистр не учитывает.
Я только в функ. понимаю с класами не очень дружу.

 jQuery.expr[":"].Contains = jQuery.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
    return function( elem ) {
        return jQuery(elem).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(arg.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
     };
 });
    function textFilter(q) {
    $('.filter #input-filter').val(q);
    $('#results .result').removeClass('needHide').children('.name').not(':contains(' + q + ')').parent('.result').addClass('needHide');
    }

Comment: not(':**C**ontains(

Comment: Вы теперь `Contains` должны с большой буквы писать, потому что это другое теперь. Оригинальное `:contains("text")` при этом остаётся.
Можете назвать `containsIC`, чтобы было понятней и ясней для себя.

Answer (score 0):

Пример с :Contains вызывал ошибку в библиотеке JQuery, поэтому пришлось переписать функцию фильтрации, тут ищем текст 'aBcDeF' (без учёта регистра) в наборе $('.class'), в итоге получаем набор элементов filtered_items, отвечающих требованию фильтра :

```
var text_to_find = 'aBcDeF';
var filtered_items = $('.class').filter(function(){
  return $(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(text_to_find.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
})
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]